# Display a tweet one at a time?

Tags: twitter

Most plugins I see says I can't use their service anymore because Twitter changed their unauthenticated API. Can someone guide me on how to get around it? We already have an embedded twitter feed, but we wanted the tweets to display one at a time, instead of the box being filled up (with a scrollbar)

Any references or guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? Can you post code?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter have introduced a system of "*Application-only authentication*" based on OAuth 2. You can use it to authenticate your app for API endpoints which do not require user related informations (basically the former endpoints which do not require authentication). With this "*Application-only authentication*" you should be able to use the methods that plugins do not handle any longer (likely because they did not code this feature). For further informations, have a look at [the corresponding page on Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).

The rest of your question is just about using the Twitter API endpoints. The available endpoints you can use (i.e. the ones that Twitter Inc. does not keep for itself only) are listed [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).